# Is there a way to get canvas data from a background image

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, canvas, todataurl

I currently have an interface with a list of product images that you can swipe through. Only - these images are set as background images for a div, so that I can use CSS's background-size: cover method to handle the sizing of the image.

What I want to be able to do is get the dominant color in these background images, and set the page background to that color. I have successfully implemented [this library](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief/) in order to grab the dominant color and accomplish this, but in order to do so, I have to grab the URL being used in the background image, create a new image with that URL as the SRC, add the temporary image to the DOM to get the dominant color, and then remove the temporary image. It's really slow and I have a feeling there might be a better way.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this faster? Preferably sampling the color straight from the div containing the background image, and not having to render a new image? Here is my code:

```
var sampleImageURL = this.productsItemsCollection.models[modelIndex].get('image');

if (sampleImageURL != ""){
  //this.setImagePalette(sampleImageURL); //MH - reenable to allow background color switching
}

setImagePalette: function(sampleImageURL){

  var $sampleImage = $('<img class="palette-image" src="' +sampleImageURL + '" style="display: none; width: 100px; height: 100px;" crossOrigin="anonymous" />'); //MH - find a better way than appending a temporary image
  $('body').append($sampleImage);
  var sampleImage = $('.palette-image')[0];

  sampleImage.addEventListener("load", _.bind(this.getImagePalette,this,sampleImage));

},

getImagePalette: function(sampleImage){
    var colorArray = this.colorThief.getColor(sampleImage);
    var sampleColorRGB = 'rgb(' + colorArray[0] + ',' + colorArray[1] + ',' + colorArray[2] + ')';
    Backbone.trigger('setBackgroundColor', sampleColorRGB);
    $('.palette-image').remove();
},
```

Comment: I think you can skip appending the image to body and getting a reference to it, `var sampleImage = new Image(); sampleImage.addEventListener(...); sampleImage.src = sampleImageUrl;` should do the trick.

Comment: Need for speed? Instead of having the client process the images on-the-fly, you could pre-process each product image once for their dominant color. Then serve this dominant color along with the image so the client has ready access to that color without any processing.

Comment: What markE says. If you have a lot of images this processing is gonna take relative much time potentially degrading the user experience. Why not consider when *uploading* an image to server for the product, do all this processing then - the image won't change and you also avoid running into CORS issues if images are moved to CDN etc. in the future (if not already).

Comment: Definitely in favor of that solution @markE - only I am not in control of the backend, so not sure if that's possible.